# SSH Connect to AWS EC2 failed after using lets-encrypt update my website

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, ssh, ubuntu-16.04, lets-encrypt

Yesterday, I updated my Django website (on AWS EC2) to HTTPS by using lets-encrypt. Everything works well. The website has HTTPS green icon as expected.

Today when I try to connect my instance by using SSH. The connection keep hunging. Finally, It give some message like "ssh: connect to host ec2-34-202-93-189.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable".

I thought it might be security group problem of this instance. So I double checked my security group setting of this instance, the SSH, HTTP and HTTPS port are all open correctly. I created another instance to test if there is any problem on my local. The new instance connected successfully. Then I apply the new instance to the security group that I made for the previous instance and It connected. Then I apply the previous instance to the new security that I made for the new instance, the connection got frozen again. I also tried to connect with putty and it was not working as well.

Now I am really confused. My local machine is Windows subsystem of Linux. My EC2 instance is Ubuntu 16. I am using Nginx as web server. My ssh command is "ssh -i blog_project.pem ubuntu@ec2-34-202-93-189.compute-1.amazonaws.com".

Here is my security group setup for the instance.

[image: security group setup]

This is the result I command "ssh -vvv -i blog_project.pem ubuntu@ec2-34-202-93-189.compute-1.amazonaws.com"

[image: ssh error]

BTW, Is there any way that I can login to my instance without ssh connection? Is there anything like console or shell inside the AWS that I can touch with my instance?

Comment: It sounds like your problem lies with the security group settings, and is unrelated to your HTTPS settings. You said you changed the security group settings on the new instance, and were unable to connect afterwards. What changes did you make?

Comment: I did not change the security group setting. I created a new instance and apply it to the same security group that I made for the previous instance and It connected. Looks like security group may not have problem.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean now. So your SSH connections are just freezing periodically? Has there been any other changes to the host configuration, such as the sshd config or iptables settings? I'm not sure how modifying your HTTPS configuration would have affected your ssh sessions.

Comment: @AfroThundr Thank you for comments. I just add the snapshot of the security group setup for the instance on my question.Yes, I made some changes on Nginx config file followed this tutorial [Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04) This tutorial is not for ec2 by the way. That is all the changes I made.

Comment: So it's not a problem with your security groups then. The tutorial you linked did involve modifying firewall rules, but assuming you didn't accidentally block SSH access, the only other culprit is the originating box. Have you tried to SSH in from a different machine? I've come across several [WSL bugs](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2278) related to SSH [not cooperating](https://superuser.com/q/1098526) with various firewalls and antivirus solutions. Perhaps you could try disabling them temporarily and see if that allows the connection through?

Comment: @AfroThundr. I modified the firewall and changed it to sudo ufw 'Nginx Full'. You remained me one thing that after I changed the ufw. I checked the ufw status. It supposed to display "OpenSSH ALLOW Anywhere" but it  did not. I thought because I use EC2. If that is so, how can I connect to instance and change the firewall configuration without using SSH?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162776/discussion-between-afrothundr-and-jeffery).

Comment: @AfroThundr Sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the instance exists on AWS, maybe a new one was created with different Public DNS (xxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com) than the one you are using in your command.

Comment: With different? I guess you forgot to end your sentence here.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I don't know how that happened :)